# How can I check if a method returns true?

Tags: php, oop, if-statement, methods, logic

I have this method for a user

```
public function isClosed(){
        $username = $this->user['username'];
        $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT user_closed FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        $row['user_closed'] = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        if($row['user_closed'] == "no"){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and when I want to display the Posts of a user, in the method to display posts I have a while loop that should break if the `user_closed` column says "yes".

```
public function loadPostsFriends(){
.
.
$added_by_obj = new User($this->connection, $added_by);
            if($added_by_obj->isClosed()){
                continue;
            }
.
.}
```

What is happening is that the while loop gets broken like this, although the first method returns that user is not closed (in the database the column `user_closed` is populated with "no".) This is confusing me, since if in the DB its "no", the if statement says if its "no", return false. The `continue` function should not be activated, right?

I know this is a newbie question, but I´m new to OOP, thanks for the help.

Comment: You probably want `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)` on line 4 there…!?

Comment: Thanks, that solved it @deceze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);` instead of this `$row['user_closed'] = mysqli_fetch_array($query);`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Why is that? You cant assign a value to a certain key in an array? @stalin wesley

Comment: you can assign . if you assign the will be like  $row['user_closed']['user_closed']